# How to copy paste row inside a loop if a cell is abiding by an if condition vba

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I built a macro to copy paste rows that contain cells that abide by an if condition. This macro measures the difference of the values between 4 pairs of cells of a row and, if the difference is bigger than the desired one, then it copy-pastes the row, that the cell containing the ‘guilty’ value (or values if all 4 comparisons are not abiding by the restrictions) belongs to (or they), in a different sheet (“WFRandVFR_performance”). At the end, it colors the "guilty" cells. Everything works fine apart from the paste part, which is provided below:

```
    Sheets("WFRandVFR_performance").Select
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Below I am posting the macro

```
 Sub WFRandVFR_performance()

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False

    Sheets("Tracker").Select

        Dim mDiff1 As Double
        mDiff1 = 0.01
        Dim mDiff2 As Double
        mDiff2 = 0.03
        Dim mDiff3 As Double
        mDiff3 = 0.01
        Dim mDiff4 As Double
        mDiff4 = 0.03

        Sheets("Tracker").Select
        For Each cell1 In Range(Range("U2"), Range("U2").End(xlDown))
        If cell1.Value - cell1.Offset(0, 1).Value > mDiff1 Or cell1.Value - cell1.Offset(0, 2).Value > mDiff2 Then
        cell1.EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("WFRandVFR_performance").Select
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
        Next cell1

        Sheets("Tracker").Select
        For Each cell2 In Range(Range("AB2"), Range("AB2").End(xlDown))
        If cell2.Value - cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value > mDiff3 Or cell2.Value - cell2.Offset(0, 2).Value > mDiff4 Then
        cell2.EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("WFRandVFR_performance").Select
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
        Next cell2

        Sheets("WFRandVFR_performance").Select

        Columns(4).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
        On Error Resume Next
        Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

        For Each cell3 In Range(Range("U2"), Range("U2").End(xlDown))
        If cell3.Value - cell3.Offset(0, 1).Value > mDiff1 Then
        cell3.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
        If cell3.Value - cell3.Offset(0, 2).Value > mDiff2 Then
        cell3.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        End If
        Next cell3

        For Each cell4 In Range(Range("AB2"), Range("AB2").End(xlDown))
        If cell4.Value - cell4.Offset(0, 1).Value > mDiff3 Then
        cell4.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
        If cell4.Value - cell4.Offset(0, 2).Value > mDiff4 Then
        cell4.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        End If
        Next cell4

        Sheets("WFRandVFR_performance").Select
        If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(1).AutoFilter
        End If

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: First comment I can say is to avoid .select/.activate whenever possible; in only a few scenarios (e.g., .FreezePanes) is .select/.activate needed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! but even with that type of specification for the ranges everything runs just fine... I just need the proper line of code to paste it correctly. The copying part is just fine. I just want to paste them in the other sheet... Thats all!

Comment: Got'cha; figured I'd add in the comment as such.  Answered below, which will hopefully solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the last row as such:

```
Dim LR as Long
LR = Sheets("WFRandVFR_performance").Cells(Sheets("WFRandVFR_performance").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

cell1.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("WFRandVFR_performance").Range("A" & LR+1)
```

---

Another option, and probably the best (avoids copy/paste):

```
Dim LR as Long
LR = Sheets("WFRandVFR_performance").Cells(Sheets("WFRandVFR_performance").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("WFRandVFR_performance").Range("A" & LR+1).Value=cell1.EntireRow.Value
```

---

Putting this into your code:

```
Dim LR as Long

Sheets("WFRandVFR_performance").Rows(1).Value=Sheets("Tracker").Rows(1).Value

    For Each cell1 In Range(Range("U2"), Range("U2").End(xlDown))
        If cell1.Value - cell1.Offset(0, 1).Value > mDiff1 Or cell1.Value - cell1.Offset(0, 2).Value > mDiff2 Then
            LR = Sheets("WFRandVFR_performance").Cells(Sheets("WFRandVFR_performance").Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            Sheets("WFRandVFR_performance").Range("A" & LR+1).Value=cell1.EntireRow.Value
        End If
    Next cell1
```

Comment: I checked the code... Now we made a little progress, as it pastes the headers successfully. However, still, it overwrites the rows and so, the last row from the initial sheet appears to be the only row in the destination sheet... Our problem is that it doesnt get the order to paste the rows on below another... it just overwrites them....

Comment: The problem must be with the last occupied row... we must tell the macro to paste it one row below the last occupied row.. not on the last occupied row..

Comment: That's what the LR+1 does, ensure that you're on the row after the last occupied.  You just need to ensure that the column you're searching in has every single row occupied.

Comment: well cyril thank you for your time and everything!! It just wouldn't work so I changed the whole approach and tried copy pasting the whole worksheet to another one and deleting the rows that didn't abide by the if condition and it worked!! Thank you everything again man!! I really appreciate it!